# How to count data in Java

Tags: java

I try count data and remove Duplicate data by the following code ,but I got an error message with this code.

Can anyone help me?

**StructorRecords.java**

```
public class StructorRecords {

public String recorusername;
public String id;
public String full_name;
public String recordimg;
public Integer count;}
```

**counter.java**

```
public static void orderbylike(StructorRecords data) {
    if (G.bollike) {
        G.savelike.add(data);
    } else {
        Iterator itr = G.savelike.iterator();
        int i = 1;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            StructorRecords SR = (StructorRecords) itr.next();
            if (SR.id.equals(data.id)) {
                data.count = SR.count + 1;
                G.savelike.set(i, data);
            } else {
                G.savelike.add(data);
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

this is logs that get me 
**LOG**

```
02-01 17:19:23.142 7587-9416/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
02-01 17:19:23.152 7587-9416/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
02-01 17:19:23.152 7587-9416/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj.counter.orderbylike(counter.java:21)
02-01 17:19:23.152 7587-9416/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj.loginActivity$11.run(loginActivity.java:460)
02-01 17:19:23.162 7587-9416/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-01 17:19:23.451 7587-9472/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
02-01 17:19:23.451 7587-9472/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
02-01 17:19:23.451 7587-9472/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj.counter.orderbylike(counter.java:21)
02-01 17:19:23.461 7587-9472/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj.loginActivity$11.run(loginActivity.java:460)
02-01 17:19:23.461 7587-9472/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-01 17:19:23.583 7587-9417/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
02-01 17:19:23.583 7587-9417/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
02-01 17:19:23.583 7587-9417/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj.counter.orderbylike(counter.java:21)
02-01 17:19:23.583 7587-9417/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj.loginActivity$11.run(loginActivity.java:460)
02-01 17:19:23.592 7587-9417/sanjinsgr.limosoftwaregroup.ir.instasanj W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Can you post error log please!So it will be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is there because
you try to add element to the List (I assume `G.savelike` is a List), while you iterate through the same list with iterator.

It is not allowed. Instead make another tmpList for all new elements, add them in it and after iterator loop done use `addAll()` method.

Like that:

```
List<StructorRecords> tmpList = new ArrayList<StructorRecords> tmpList;
while (itr.hasNext()) {
        StructorRecords SR = (StructorRecords) itr.next();
        if (SR.id.equals(data.id)) {
            data.count = SR.count + 1;
            G.savelike.set(i, data);
        } else {
            // here put to temp list
            tmpList.add(data);
        }
        i++;
    }
    // add all new elements
    G.savelike.addAll(tmpList);
```

Comment: BTW: List index starts from 0, not from 1, so it seems like code may fail on the last element when `G.savelike.set(i, data);` invoked...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Collections from java concurrency package which will provide fail safe iterator, If you use Collections from `java.util` package the iterators are of Fail fast type and will throw Concurrent modification exception whenever you iterate and try update the collection at the same time.